# LoadLibrary("MSVCR90D.dll") Fail

Tags: mfc, dialog, loadlibrary

Oh, I don't know what's the matter with this loadlibrary("MSVCR90d.dll").

It always return 0x00000000.

Here is code.

HModule hMod = LoadLibrary("MSVCR90D.dll");

Please tell me the reason.

< I simply made MFC Application Program. >

Comment: Why are you trying to dynamically load MSVCR90d.dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a call to `GetLastError()` after the failure to get a little more info. It's either that your app can't find it or that a dependency of the DLL itself is not found.

Install [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and right-click on MSVCR90D.dll to 'View Dependencies' to see if that DLL itself can load ok.